# Small String hashing and compare

Tags: c++, strings

The idea is to convert first 8 character from the C string to `uint64_t` or `uint32_t`, then to convert to Big Endian.

The value can be stored and compared with same values and result will be compatible with `memcmp` or `strcmp`.

The only exception is if both "strings" are 8 bytes long or 4 bytes long for `uint32_t` and are equal, the function must return sentinel value, e.g. `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`, so caller to know he will need to compare the real strings in order to find the result.

For simplicity, I assume code runs on Little Endian machine and convert to Big Endian is done by `__builtin_bswap64` (available on gcc and clang).

Here is the code + some tests

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <limits>

namespace sshhash_implementation{
    constexpr auto bswap(uint64_t x){
        return __builtin_bswap64(x);
    }

    constexpr auto bswap(uint32_t x){
        return __builtin_bswap32(x);
    }

    template<typename T>
    T hash(const char *src){
        constexpr auto capacity = sizeof(T);

        union{
            char    s[capacity];
            T   u = 0;
        };

        strncpy(s, src, capacity);
        return bswap(u);
    }

    template<typename T>
    constexpr T mask(){
        return bswap(T{ 0xFF } << (sizeof(T) - 1) * 8);
    }

    template<typename T>
    int sscmp(T const a, T const b){
        if (a > b)
            return +1;

        if (a < b)
            return -1;

        // equal, check size

        constexpr auto m = mask<T>();

        if ( (a | b) & m )
            return std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

        return 0;
    }
}


template<typename T>
auto sshash(const char *s){
    return sshhash_implementation::hash<T>(s);
}

auto sshash8(const char *s){
    return sshash<uint64_t>(s);
}


auto sshash4(const char *s){
    return sshash<uint32_t>(s);
}

template<typename T>
auto sscmp(T a, T b){
    return sshhash_implementation::sscmp(a, b);
}

auto sscmp8(uint64_t a, uint64_t b){
    return sscmp(a, b);
}

auto sscmp4(uint32_t a, uint32_t b){
    return sscmp(a, b);
}

#include <cstdio>

template<typename T = uint32_t>
void testC(const char *sa, const char *sb, bool const overflow){
    auto const a = sshash<T>(sa);
    auto const b = sshash<T>(sb);

    int const  x = strncmp(sa, sb, sizeof(T));
    int const  y = sscmp(a, b);

    bool const ok = [=](){
        if (overflow)
            return x == 0 && y == std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
        else
            return x == y;
    }();

    printf(
        "%-8s | %-8s | %2d | %2d | %-8s\n",
        sa,
        sb,
        x,
        y,
        ok ? "OK" : "Error"
    );
}

template<typename T = uint32_t>
void test(const char *sa, const char *sb, bool const overflow = false){
    testC(sa, sb, overflow);
    testC(sb, sa, overflow);
}

int main(){
    test("aaa"  , "aaa"     );

    test("aaa"  , "b"       );
    test("aaaa" , "b"       );
    test("aaa"  , "bbbb"    );
    test("aaaa" , "bbbb"    );

    test("aaaa" , "aaaa", true  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since we assume GCC or Clang, we can easily make the code adapt to the target's endianness:

```
#if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
    constexpr auto hton(std::uint64_t x){
        return __builtin_bswap64(x);
    }

    constexpr auto hton(std::uint32_t x){
        return __builtin_bswap32(x);
    }
#elif __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__
    constexpr auto hton(std::uint64_t x){
        return x;
    }

    constexpr auto hton(std::uint32_t x){
        return x;
    }
#else
#error Unsupported byte order
#endif
```

I've used the conventional "host to net" name for the function, to be clearer.

---

Some identifiers are misspelt: `std::uint32_t`, `std::uint64_t`, `std::strncpy`, `std::strncmp`, `std::printf`.

---

This function is unnecessary:

> ```
> template<typename T>
> auto sscmp(T a, T b){
>     return sshhash_implementation::sscmp(a, b);
> }
> ```

Much simpler to write

using sshhash_implementation::sscmp;

---

No need for the immediately-executed lambda in `testC()`:

> ```
> bool const ok = [=](){
>     if (overflow)
>         return x == 0 && y == std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
>     else
>         return x == y;
> }();
> ```

That can be written as a simple expression:

```
bool const ok = overflow
    ? x == 0 && y == std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
    : x == y;
```

---

In `mask()`, I think the constant `8` was intended to be `CHAR_BIT`, since it's converting a count of `char` to number of bits.